# How to reduce the app size after use of FFMPEG in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I'm current using `ffmpeg_kit_flutter 4.5.1-LTS` after that my app bundle size increase by 150mb and final bundle size is 250 mb.

Is there any way to reduce the app bundle size with FFMPEG.

Comment: try to find ffmpeg `shared` build

Comment: Can you please explain me more about this.

Comment: Ah sorry, i think your ffmpeg is `shared` build, because its size is about 100MB. Then you need a server to download ffmpeg as resources.

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce app size with [Reducing the package binary size](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/wiki/How-to-Decrease-Binary-Size).

Refer the Git [discussion](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/discussions/582) and [issue](https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/issues/592).